# When I am installing other applications, it shows error

Tags: software-installation

I am going to install Python software in Ubuntu 20.04, then it shows below mentioned errors everytime:

> please insert the disc labeled `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)` in the drive `/media/cdrom/` and press [Enter]

Please help me solve my issues.

Comment: please read [ask] and [edit] your question with required details at the same time removing the all caps which is regarded as shouting and unwelcome.

Comment: Tell us what method you followed in installing the same.

Comment: iam going to install windows office on ubuntu, and then its shows

Comment: @SureshaN your question get's increasingly confusing for people over here. You might wanna rephrase.

Comment: Open software sources and untick the cdrom option. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/SJBgZQF.png).